# Debian can not dist-upgrade because of unmet dependencies, but there are no held packages

Tags: debian, upgrade

I am running Debian stretch (9.9) and I can't dist-upgrade. I have no held packages.

My version and kernel:

```
lsb_release -a

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 9.9 (stretch)
Release:    9.9
Codename:   stretch


uname -a

beastmode 4.17.0-0.bpo.1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.17.8-1~bpo9+1 (2018-07-23) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

My apt-mark showhold command shows no held packages.

```
me@pc:~$ sudo apt-mark showhold
me@pc:~$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Error!
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libkf5su-bin : Depends: libkf5su5 (>= 4.96.0) but it is not going to be installed
 monodoc-browser : Depends: libwebkit1.1-cil (>= 0.3) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

The broken package from KDE (libkf5su-bin) can be removed, but monodoc-browser is NOT EVEN INSTALLED and I didn't ask for it to be installed.

What do I do to repair my system?

(Update: I think I need to remove anything installed that appears in the list, and add anything that isn't installed yet, that appears in the list of brokenness. )

(Update: Third party repos are a huge source of pain! )

Comment: What is the contents of your `sources.list`?

Comment: Have you run `apt-get update` to refresh the local package list?

Comment: @WarrenP You should also note that you are on the latest release of Debian 9 so running `apt-get dist-upgrade` should not install anything _if you are up to date_ new unless your `sources.list` has non-stretch (stable) repos.

Comment: Could you show the output of `apt policy`? Do you have a reference to Microsoft’s repositories by any chance? They are currently [breaking KDE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/523520/86440), apparently.

Comment: I do have a Visual Studio Code MS APT repo.  I also had some odd backports installed.  I removed both and the problem is solved. Thanks

Comment: @WarrenP please consider moving your answer out of the question and into an answer and accepting. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The following steps were needed:

1. remove third party sources that may have bad dependencies (MS VS CODE and SKYPE repos)
2. Remove installed items that came up in the error list.
3. INSTALL the items that came up in the error list as bad dependencies, but which were not installed.

Afterwards having completely uninstalled KDE (which seems to have been broken by the MS REPO), I had to reinstall KDE or some other desktop. I decided to switch to Mate instead of reinstalling KDE.